# Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter allow POST?

Tags: java, spring, http

I would like to enable POST request for a certain "/interface" URL on my site. I have successfully loaded the class via `Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()`, the specified CSP header for the `HttpSecurity http` exist.

Whenever I make a request to `/interface`, I get `HTTP 403`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/interface").permitAll().and()
            .headers()
            .contentTypeOptions().and()
            .cacheControl().and()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().and()
            .frameOptions().and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("the csp header. it is present on every response.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact message returned with http code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try overriding another configuration method: `configure(WebSecurity webSecurity)`.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
    webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers(POST, "/interface");
}
```